# Running html and JS in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a web app, which contains a set of html, js and some static files like images,videos etc.
Specifically, I don't need a web server to run them. I can rum them in the desktop browser as a file protocol don't need the http protocol.

But when I take the same set of files in Android , it does not run and says Javascript is turned off (Android's stock browser, Firefox, Chrome or Opera). However, Javascript is turned on.

Do I need to serve the files from a web server or use http protocol if I am on android?

Comment: Have a look at [WebApp/WebView docs #javascript](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript) and make sure you are doing everything right.

Comment: Can you post any code? Did you used:
`webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` ??

Comment: yes i did enable...the html and java script code right now i can not post here as that is company confidential :)...my question is simply if the html and js should run the standard android browser ?

Comment: @MarcusGabilheri also i am just trying to run my files through the file protocol...once it works then  i will play them in my app using web view